# Is there no race condition in the swap?

Tags: c++, atomic

Global:

```
std::atomic<T*> a, b;
```

In thread A:

```
// this like std::swap(a, b), but is it atomic?
a.exchange(b.exchange(a));
```

In thread B:

```
T* p = a.load();
doSomethine(p);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequences of atomic operations aren't atomic.  Something could happen between `b.exchange` and `a.exchange`, and observe that both `a` and `b` have the same value (the original value of `a`).

If you don't want this, use some type of lock.